# Correct Use of the "runif" Command

Tags: r, random, grid, data-manipulation

I am trying to make a "self referencing grid" - i.e. a grid with certain conditions. For each row within this grid:

- var_2 must always be greater than var_1
- var_4 must always be greater than var_3
- var_6 must always be greater than var_5
- var_7 must always be greater than var_6

Here is my own attempt to answer this using the "runif" command (I thought that I can incorporate these "conditions" by setting the "lower limit" of the "bigger variable" to the "smaller variable"):

```
#https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/Uniform
    var_1 <- runif(1000, 0, 100)
    var_2 <- runif(1000, var_1, 100)
    var_3 <- runif(1000, 0, 100)
    var_4 <- runif(1000, var_3, 100)
    var_5 <- runif(1000, 0, 100)
    var_6 <- runif(1000, var_5, 100)
    var_7 <- runif(1000, var_6, 100)

frame_3 <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6, var_7)


head(frame_3)
      var_1    var_2    var_3    var_4     var_5    var_6    var_7
1 16.824184 42.45956 26.68427 41.69108 66.104877 67.29392 92.26807
2  5.154861 74.42316 32.87011 73.93285  3.206936 62.48352 63.06708
3 35.263069 48.56498 34.64460 39.81641 12.816591 13.17151 72.77144
4 21.175502 27.04440 18.04221 64.40537 34.614670 65.89940 92.80989
5 17.156617 86.05252 10.88137 84.53697 86.133523 99.04071 99.55816
6 32.293821 89.77986 26.29747 49.53139 76.262548 81.88121 89.91402
```

Based on some manual checks, I think this might be correct.

My Question: Is there a "better" way to solve this problem? For instance - can this be done using the "expand.grid" command or with "loops"?

Comment: what do you mean by greater?? Elementwise or all the elements in one vector greater than all elements in another?? How do you define A>B when both are vectors?

Comment: @Onyambu : I mean, for any given row

Comment: What do you mean by better? If you're looking for a check that `var_2>var_1` you could ask `sum(var_2<var_1)`. Are you looking for speed of execution? Or code readability?

Comment: @PeterK: thank you for your reply! I come from a non computer science background, and have been trying to teach myself R. As a result, many of the solutions I come up with are not very "compact" and often inefficient. My code looks as if a beginner has written it. I am trying to learn alternate ways to solve this problem, as well as more "conventional" ways to solve this problem.

Comment: @ PeterK" did you have any thoughts about this? thanks

Comment: Congratulations @Noob on engaging in coding as a non-professional. It's an important skill and an excellent thing to do. My philosophy, FWIW, is that the most important thing is for the code to be readable by you so that you have some chance of detecting errors and evolving the code as your problem evolves. The next most important thing is to minimize time spent writing code, which will be far longer than the time it takes to run.